# How to use chrome remote debugging with ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

So I'm reading in [this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html)  and it says we can use chrome for remote debugging an app which seeems great but they don't explain how to do it. When  I click in the [link they provide which has some android documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews), I just see java code. As a non java-developer I wonder how can I use remote debugger in chrome for ionic framework?

Comment: plug your phone into the pc, go to chrome. then type: chrome://inspect into the url bar. open your app on your phone.

Comment: hi @letterman549, thanks that worked great, if you can convert this comment into an answer I can upvote your answer, since comment don't receive points :)

Comment: Glad it helped :) will do the old copy paste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access remote debugging of a webview on your phone, plug your phone into your pc and go to chrome. then type: chrome://inspect into the url bar. open your app on your phone and it should show your device on the inspect dashboard.

Comment: My pleasure :) glad you are sorted.

Comment: In case this doesn't work for someone, make sure adb server is running (go to [AndroidSDKInstall]/sdk/platform-tools and open a command prompt and run 'adb start-server')

Comment: @babycakes I did it. Just like the answer said and your suggestion. I see my device in ht inspector. But when I launch the app, I don't see anything else in the inspector (console, network, etc...) nothing...